# Facing issues with named export when I try to run jest unit testing

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs, tsconfig

I am trying to write unit test cases but when I run command npm run test for the specific file, I am getting error  `Cannot find module '@decorators'` for named exports I have added for my application. There is one more named export `@entities` which is throwing same issue.below is my jest config file which I have added in root folder. I am using nestjs project to be clear.

```
module.exports = {
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'json', 'ts'],
  rootDir: '.',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(t|j)s$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@entities/(.*)$': 'src/entities/$1',
    '^@decorators/(.*)$': 'src/utils/decorators/$1',
  },
};
```

Help me find solution for this. Tried multiple ways in jest config also but nothing seems to work.

Update jest config in package.json

```
"jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^src/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/$1",
      "^@decorators/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/utils/decorators/$1",
      "^entities/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/entities/$1"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
```

detailed error

```
Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module '@decorators' from 'modules/test2/entities/test2.entity.ts'

    Require stack:
      modules/test2/entities/test2.entity.ts
      modules/test1/entities/test1.entity.ts
      entities/index.ts
      modules/test-module/test.service.ts
      modules/test-module/test.service.spec.ts

      1 | import { ObjectType } from '@nestjs/graphql';
      2 | import { Entity } from 'typeorm';
    > 3 | import {
        | ^
      4 |   TimestampColumnOptional,
      5 |   StringColumnOptional,
      6 |   IntColumnOptional,
      at Resolver._throwModNotFoundError (../node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:428:11)
```

I have added some custom decorators which I am using in entity file. After named export, I am importing it like below example. Project works fine but unit test cases throwing the issue I mentioned.

```
import {
  IntColumnOptional,
  StringColumnOptional,
  BooleanColumnOptional
} from '@decorators';
```

Comment: Where is the above file located? What's the full error (just to make sure we can provide support)? We need more information here

Comment: 1. entities are in src/entities/index.ts file
2. decorators are in src/utils/decorators/index.ts
3. the above code was in jest.config.js in src folder but I have moved the configurations to jest field of package.json file

Comment: I replaced named exports with src/entities and same for decorators and it worked by adding that path alias of src but its not working in case of named exports for some reasons.

Comment: I have attached update package.json in the main question in case you want some more details

Answer (score 0):

`"^@decorators/(.*)$` does not match `@decorators`, so Jest cannot know what `@decorators` is referring to file wise. More than likely, add `^@decorators$': 'src/utils/decorators'` to the jest config and everything will work out as expected

Comment: Thanks . still same error as mentioned above. Providing updated jest config
`
"jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^src/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/$1",
      "^@decorators$": "src/utils/decorators",
      "^@entities$": "src/utils/entities"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
`